# Change Password Button - how to overwrite current user password?

Tags: java, netbeans, passwords, overwrite

I am programming a Change Password button, I am having problems with overwriting the password saved in a text file.

So imagine there is a username and password saved in a text file respectively:

```
John01

1871993

$$$

Jessica

123456

$$$

(...)
```

how can I overwrite for example user: John01 current password "1871993" with a new password entered after clicking the Change Password button?

All what I have right now is saving the same username with the new password.

This is the code for my change password button:

```
if (ChangePassword())
{
    if (EnterCurrentPasswordTextField.getText().trim().length() != 0 
        && NewPasswordTextField.getText().trim().length() != 0
        && ConfirmNewPasswordTextField.getText().trim().length() != 0)
    {

        if (NewPasswordTextField.getText().equals(ConfirmNewPasswordTextField.getText()))
        {


                FileWriter out = null;
            try{
                out = new FileWriter("login.txt", true);

                out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));          
                out.append(NameTextField.getText());
                out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                out.append(ConfirmNewPasswordTextField.getText());
                out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                out.append("$$$");
                out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                out.close();
                out=null;
                }catch(IOException ioe){
                    NameTextField.setText("IOProblem");
                    }

                StatusMessageLabel.setText(NameTextField.getText() + " you have succesfully changed your password");
                MainTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(0, false);  
                MainTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, true);
                MainTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(2, true);
                MainTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(3, true);        
                MainTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(4, true);
                MainTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(5, false);
                MainTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(2);

        }
        else {
            StatusMessageLabel.setText("ERROR: Please confirm your New Password is identical in both fields!");
        }
    }
    else {
        StatusMessageLabel.setText("ERROR: Please enter all empty fields!");
    }    
}    
else {
    StatusMessageLabel.setText("ERROR: Wrong Current Password Details!!");
}
```

Comment: you want to change the stored password with the new password. ?

Comment: Use a Properties file. Read in on program start and if user changes write back the file. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: ... and try to use Java Coding Conventions (or do not overuse static methods)

Comment: PLEASE avoid storing passwords in plaintext files. It's a security hole easily avoided.

Comment: how could I use .replace in my change password code?

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer what is another option?

Comment: @user2001913 - One way is to store a one-way hash of the password plus some user-specific salt, and the salt itself.

Answer (score 1):

Load your current password/username file in into a Map find your entry and write out your Map entries,  Maybe a better solution would be to use some kind of in memory database.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a [`MappedByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).